# Use object in class function

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to C++ and I'm running into problems trying to use one class object in another class function. For example if I have:

```
#ifndef CARD_HPP
#define CARD_HPP
#include <string>

enum Suits
{
SPADES,
CLUBS,
HEARTS,
DIAMONDS
};

enum Values
{
TWO,
THREE,
FOUR,
FIVE,
SIX,
SEVEN,
EIGHT,
NINE,
TEN,
JACK,
QUEEN,
KING,
ACE
};


class Card
{
public:
    Card(Values value, Suits suit);
    Values getValue() const;
    Suits getSuit() const;
    void showCard();
    std::string toString(Values v);
    std::string toString(Suits s);

private:
    Suits suit;
    Values value;

};
```

and:

```
#ifndef DECK_OF_CARDS_HPP
#define DECK_OF_CARDS_HPP

#include "card.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <string>

Values enumValueOfIndex(int i);
Suits enumSuitOfIndex(int i);

class DeckOfCards
{
public:
    DeckOfCards();
    void shuffleDeck();
    void printDeck();
    Card drawCard();

private:
    const std::string suit_strings[4];
    const std::string value_strings[13];
    unsigned seed;
    Values values;
    Suits suits;
    std::string suit;
    std::string value;
    std::vector<Card> deck;
};

#endif
```

I'm having an error when in my `Deck::printDeck()` when trying to do:

```
Card card = deck.at(i); //I have already added 52 card objects to deck
```

The error I am getting is:

```
error: non-object type 'Card (Values, Suits)' is not assignable
    card = deck.at(i);
```

I am essentially using old Java code to make this and that is essentially what I did. I don't know if I need to define/declare a `Card` object in my `Deck` header/source or even how to do that. I feel like this is a simple problem but I can't find any solution to it. Thank you for any help!

Comment: at returns a reference to the object but that shouldn't be the problem, probably there's no copy constructor defined properly

Comment: I think we need to see more of your `Card` class declaration. What are your member variables? Any `const` or reference member variables? Any ` = delete` member functions? Inheriting from `boost::noncopyable` or something?

Comment: Hmmm, "non-object type" is fishy. Is `Card` undeclared or an incomplete type at that point?

Comment: Ok I added my complete header files if that helps!

Comment: Are you getting more error messages than the one you posted?

Comment: No that was the only one

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to define a copy constructor and assignment operator, try adding:

```
Card(const Card& rhs);
Card& operator=(const Card& rhs);
```

Comment: Although they should be provided by the compiler, if they're not explicitly disabled. Right?

Comment: perhaps there's more on the code and it hasn't been pasted

Comment: @FredLarson Only if all of the class member variables are also trivially copyable.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Yes, that would do it too. But the message about "non-object type" makes me thing `Card` is not declared at that point.

Comment: @FredLarson Yeah, sounds like! I read your other comment. May be, you should make this an answer.

Comment: @rsay3: Did this solve your problem? I can't see why it would be necessary given the declaration you've posted.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize I accidentally clicked the answer button. I did solve my problem but I don't really know how. I was going back and forth between here and my code, I added the copy constructor, then deleted it, built my code and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a copy-assignment constructor for your class will make the `=` (assignment operator) to run in your program.

```
Card( const Card & input );
```

If you want to assign a special meaning for the `=` operator, then you should override it. Below you can find some resources that will help you:

- [C++ Primer 5th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714113) book. Chapter 7.1.5 will help you understanding the class special functions
- [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) you will find some other references, that are free.
- [Here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/911-the-copy-constructor-and-overloading-the-assignment-operator/), you will find out more about operator overloading.